# How to Get finger print image from scanner and use it in User Registration Form

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a project in PHP,
I want to use fingerprint scanner and take image from scanner and use it in User Registration form and then save to database...
Is it possible?
if yes then please help me to sort out it....
Thanx in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything? I've just done a quick google search and there are an abundance of results.

Comment: I second @Loki's request to do some prior research. If you don't already have one, buy a scanner so you can play with it. What interface are you expecting - USB? Will drivers be available for the operating system upon which you are running PHP? Does your chosen scanner manufacturer offer any utility programs to scan fingerprints and then later to use them for authentication? (Importantly, do you know if your target audience will let you take their fingerprints?)

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to make the fingerprint and just save it, thats possible, basically just upload the image. If you want to scan it inside the browser and save it, maybe compare it with another fingerprint php alone wont help you.